# Handle warnings in data processing with apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I looked around on the web and I couldn’t find any way to deal in a structured way with malformed/faulty records during computation. All I was able to find was the flatMap/Some/None technique + logging.
I’m facing this problem because I have a processing algorithm that extracts more than one value from each record, but can fail in extracting one of those multiple values, and I want to keep track of them. Logging is not feasible because this “warning” happens so frequently that the logs would become overwhelming and impossibile to read.

Since I have 3 different possible outcomes from my processing I modeled it with this class hierarchy:

[image]

That holds result and/or warnings.

Since Result implements Traversable it can be used in a flatMap, discarding all warnings and failure results, in the other hand, if we want to keep track of warnings, we can elaborate them and output them if we need.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Did you have a question about it?

Comment: The question is: Is there any best practice in the spark world? Or I should rely on my custom solution?

Comment: I don't know of anything better for this. I would probably have just done it with a class that has a `warning: Option[String]` field. But your solution is more elegant.